# how to reload response content in scrapy after in each timer?

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to retrieve the contents of a dynamic HTML table after each timer, but the response is always the same after each scrapping;
But I do not know how to do it then I'm new with scrapy; here is my code content

```
# redirection sur la page
def parse_x(self,response):

    for q in response.xpath('//*[@id="sessions"]/tbody/tr'):
        # recuperation des informations localisé dans la tableau user_session sur la page
        instance_name = q.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
        username = q.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first()
        client_address = q.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first()
        environnement = q.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first()
    Timer(5, self.parse_x, [response]).start()
```

Comment: scrapy is not a browser, looks like you need something like selenium. Please look into javascript rendering for knowing more about the subject.

Comment: This can be considered a duplicate question but most questions dont have an accepted answer (which I'm not sure why) and the title's are varied. There's a few ways to handle this. I prefer [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) plugin, selenium + phantomjs is the other.

Comment: thast's not working in my case